# One time binding called infinitely many times. Why?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, one-time-binding

### One time binding does not work in AngularJS. Why?

Here is the piece of code:

```
<div ng-repeat="c in ::relatedCasesInfo.hideRelations(type.cases, info) 
       | limitTo:relatedCasesInfo.initialRelationsAmount track by c.idFromFirst"
     class="initial-case-container">
    <ng-include ng-repeat="name in [c.name + (type.otherCasesArePresent || !$last || type.cases.length > relatedCasesInfo.initialRelationsAmount ? ', ' : '' )]"
        src="'dist/directiveTemplates/card/controls/relatedCases/casesContextMenu.html?v=' + $root.appVersion">
    </ng-include>
</div>
```

Here is the `hideRelations` function:

```
function hideRelations(relations, info) {
    return relations;
};
```

After running the html I see that the `hideRelations` is called infinitely many times. Why? What may I be missing here?

Comment: I guess `hideRelations` has more logic inside it, why do you need to bind the function in the view?

Comment: Before include check the list if contains any item.(ng-if="if has value")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The framework re-calculates because the function either returns the value `undefined` or the calculation is unstable.

From the Docs:

> ## One-time binding
>
> An expression that starts with `::` is considered a one-time expression. One-time expressions **will stop recalculating once they are stable**, which happens after the first digest if the expression result is a non-undefined value (see [value stabilization algorithm](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#value-stabilization-algorithm)).

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - One-time Binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#value-stabilization-algorithm)